# How do I restore the Top Link Bar in the Site Settings menu?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, navigation

The Top Link bar is showing however I do not have the Top Link Bar option under Look and Feel within Site Settings. What is needed to restore the option to the settings menu to allow for changes to be made to the Top Link bar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **Top Link Bar** option is only available when you have the **publishing features** deactivated (*SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure* feature under *Site Collection Features* to be specific).

For sites that have publishing features turned on, you would see **Navigation** instead.

Reference: [Customize the top link bar.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/customize-the-top-link-bar-HA010255193.aspx)