# why communication site Top navigation menu disappear when activate Publishing Infrastructure

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, publishing

I have created a communication site and activated the Publishing Infrastructure by running this PowerShell command

Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com

Set-SPOSite -Identity https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Publishing -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0

Connect-PnPOnline -url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Publishing

Enable-PnPFeature -Identity dffaae84-60ee-413a-9600-1cf431cf0560 -force #RollupPages

Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416 -force #Publishing

Enable-PnPFeature -Identity f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa -force -Scope site #SharePoint Server

Publishing Infrastructure of Site Collection

Enable-PnPFeature -Identity 94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb -force -Scope web #SharePoint Server

Publishing Infrastructure of Site

But when I do that I don't see the top navigation menu any more only the Hub menu

[image]

What I am missing??

Answer (score 0):

Whether all users cannot see the top navigation after activating feature “SharePoint server publishing infrastructure”?

I have done a test in my SharePoint online and I cannot reproduce your issue.

Top navigation will not disappear in modern page when active feature “SharePoint server publishing infrastructure”.

Try to create a new modern page and compare the results.

Comment: Recreate another communication site with same process above and still get the same result

Comment: No Global Navigation

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but it seems like "The Top Link Bar option is only available when you have the publishing features deactivated (SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature under Site Collection Features to be specific)."
source: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/284188/94497